# ListBox adding item spacing

Tags: listbox, vb6

This is the list box I have created in my form.

[image]

What I need is to modify the listBox items list as follows by adding item spacing.
[image]

I searched through the web and applied the solutions I found, in my code, but nothing worked. 
This is my code for adding items to the listBox.

```
With mobjApplication
    List1.AddItem vbCrLf + " " + .GetUIString("frmSettings.ServerConnections") + vbCrLf + "", 0
    List1.AddItem " " + .GetUIString("frmSettings.WorkflowOptions") & "", 1
    List1.AddItem " " + .GetUIString("frmSettings.Appearance") & "", 2
    List1.AddItem " " + .GetUIString("frmSettings.FileLocations") & "", 3 
End with
```

Please anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const LB_SETITEMHEIGHT As Long = &H1A0&

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT As Long = 40 'Pixels.

    With List1
        .Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
        .Font.Size = 14
        SendMessage .hWnd, LB_SETITEMHEIGHT, 0, LIST_ITEM_HEIGHT
        .AddItem "Server Connections"
        .AddItem "Workflow Options"
        .AddItem "Appearance"
        .AddItem "File Locations"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell me what improvement should I added to this code to make the text added in the list item align to the middle.

Comment: Probably only possible for an owner-drawn ListBox.

Comment: Can I add a 'new line' inside the list box item text ? I tried using vbCrLf and vbNewLine. But they didn't work.

Comment: I doubt it, the text probably isn't rendered using a multi-line text drawing call.

Comment: I am having a problem with my code. I am working on creating a word add-in. I added the above code piece to my form and then it worked well as I expected. But now I tried creating the .dll file and run it with word 2016, 2013 and 2007. But the listbox items displayed without the added item height. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code as per @Bob77's answer,  but I was unable to make the listbox items vertically aligned to the center of it's item space.

[image]

As per Bob, we need to create owner-drawn list box to achieve it. 
So I tried to find another control instead of listBox and tried with listView and Treeview. I tried with "Segoe UI" as per @Giorgio's answer. 
Treeview gave the most item spacing with this font, and it somewhat filled my expectation.

My UI is as follows now.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can't add 'item space' in ListBox. There are not spaces between items in image (Word Options). 
To mimic the list below (Word Options), try to set your listbox:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    List1.Font.Name = "Segoe UI"
    List1.Font.Size = 20
End Sub
```

[image]